# helm template --debug or helm install --dry-run --debug , which is best?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I would like to know which is best between `helm template --debug`
and  `helm install --dry-run --debug`

Thank you

Answer (score 16):

The difference between the two commands is that `helm install --dry-run` will send things to a Kubernetes cluster, but `helm template` won't.

My general experience has been that debugging intricate Go templates can be tricky, and if I'm having YAML issues (and especially if I have the Kubernetes API documentation up in a browser tab) the `helm template` output is more than sufficient for my needs, and is a little faster and has fewer dependencies.  So I frequently use `helm template`.

In contrast, by the time I've gotten the Go templating logic and YAML formatting correct, I'm usually ready to actually do a test deployment; so when I `helm install` it's almost never with `--dry-run`.  If I've gotten the object layout wrong this will still complain, and if it's right then I'm ready to start sending requests to the service.

Answer (score 14):

*This is an addition to the answer of David*

I always use `helm template --debug`

A common problem when developing helm templates are whitespace errors (for example incorrect indentations).

Only `helm template --debug` (but neither `helm install` nor plain `helm template`) will generate the invalid yaml, which can be used for easy debugging, because the helm error messages are rarely helpful.